# ValueError while computing convolution using scipy

Tags: python, convolution

```
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np

with open("Data.dat", "r+") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [s.strip() for s in content]
    content = np.asarray(content)
    weights = np.array([1, 2, 4, 2, 1])
    final = np.empty(content)
    ndimage.filters.convolve1d(content, weights, -1, final, 'reflect', 0.0, 0.0)
```

Here `np` is the `numpy` package. The length of `content` is 750, so tried to initialize the shape of the output array with np.empty() as I don't want any value in that.

But when I run I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Animesh\Desktop\Smoothing.py", line 18, in <module>
final = np.empty(content)
ValueError: sequence too large; must be smaller than 32
```

What should be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `final` an empty array of the same shape and dtype as `content`, use:

```
final = np.empty_like(content)
```

---

Regarding the `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`:

Although the docstring for convolve1d says

```
origin : scalar, optional
    The `origin` parameter controls the placement of the filter.
    Default 0.0.
```

the `origin` argument must be an integer, not a float.

Here is an example which runs without error:

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import numpy as np

# content = np.genfromtxt('Data.dat')
content = np.asarray(np.arange(750))
weights = np.array([1, 2, 4, 2, 1])
final = np.empty_like(content)
ndimage.convolve1d(content, weights, axis=-1, output=final, mode='reflect', cval=0.0,
                   origin=0
                   # origin=0.0  # This raises TypeError
                   )
print(final)
```

Uncommenting `origin=0.0` raises the TypeError.

---

Regarding

```
with open("Data.dat", "r+") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [s.strip() for s in content]
    content = np.asarray(content)
```

This makes `content` an array of strings. Since you are taking a convolution, you must want an array of numbers. So instead replace the above with

```
content = np.genfromtxt('Data.dat')
```

Comment: I tried that but I got this error `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`

Comment: I am making an edit to the question to show what exactly I am doing!

Comment: Change the final argument from `0.0` to `0`. The origin argument must be an integer.

Comment: I wanted to know why did you reshape the array ?

Comment: `ndimage` functions are usually applied to images, which are 2D.

Comment: Will this `reshape` affect the answer as I am actually dealing with a 1D signal i.e. `content` of length 750 ?

Comment: The reshape would definitely change the result. I'll change my example to make content a 1D array. `ndimage.convolve1d` can work there too.